# Link being replaced by a broken "rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn" link

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, broken-links

On [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/320130/is-it-true-that-the-keyboards-for-laptops-are-not-sold-separately/320133#320133) my link

> "Keysonic Compact Wireless Keyboard" which points to
>
> http://www.amazon.co.uk/Keysonic-Wireless-Keyboard-Integrated-Frequency/dp/B000L10Y5E

appears to be being dynamically replaced by a broken link that points to

> http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000L10Y5E

I have a suspicion that this is cause by my original link pointing to Amazon.**co.uk** rather than Amazon.**com**  as entering a valid "B...." number from an Amazon.com page does work.  For example:

> http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003687WV8

Granted I could try and limit my answers to Amazon.com links, but this is counter-intuitive for me as I always end up being supplied Amazon.co.uk links when searching via Google.

Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Comment: Looks like we ended up opting for rewriting `.com` links only, so .co.uk and such end up being left alone.

Comment: @Oded This appears to still be broken (or has since been re-broken) as the link on my original answer is still being rewritten to a broken address.  My answer was merged and the new link is http://superuser.com/a/320133/19943.  It is getting rewritten to http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000L10Y5E which goes to a broken `amazon.com` address, manually changing to `amazon.co.uk` gets the right page.

Comment: Resaved the post after a single space edit (so it has a diff). That "rebaked" the post, including the amazon link, which is now OK.

Comment: @Oded Thanks, I didn't realise it was that simple.  I don't have a problem with the affiliate link, just that it was broken.

Comment: We save an HTML copy of a post on save - so, if the rendered is borked for a bit and causes such issues, unless someone goes in and edits it... the original bad HTML will be served. This is really rare (old broken posts that were not edited).

Comment: @Oded FYI a user on SU [found out that the affiliate link doesn't get inserted](http://meta.superuser.com/a/8250/) when linking to `https://www.amazon.com/` or `http(s)://smile.amazon.com/`. You guys may be interested in fixing that.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @nhinkle - will talk it over with the team

Comment: @Oded would you guys also consider having all Amazon Affiliate links go to http://smile.amazon.com? The user can then choose a non-profit to receive 0.5% of their purchase, and the affiliate referral fees are the same as on the main site.

Comment: @Oded Will it be fixed within 6-8 weeks? (Yes, I am using the figurative definition).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - dunno if it will ever be. The number of people utilizing workarounds like those is minuscule, not worth our time.

Comment: @Oded But isn't it better to take preemptive measures in case there are lots of people in the future making use of these workarounds?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - not with the amount of money we are talking about.

Comment: @Oded Okay...but *if* it became a problem, would it be easy or hard to implement?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - shouldn't be difficult. IIRC the amazon link rewriting is done in a single spot, so not a huge task.

Answer (score 11):

*I work for Amazon.com.*

The reason for this is that ASINs (the 'B...' number referred to by the OP) are not technically global - they are tied to a given marketplace (.com, .ca, .co.uk etc). Products can vary from region to region, and may not even be sold in a particular marketplace.

In this case I suspect that the aforementioned Keysonic keyboard is not sold in the US, so when being redirected to the US site, there is of course no product to display.

Note that books are less likely to have this issue because the ASIN in that case always matches the book's ISBN, which tends to be global. It's still not always the case though, particularly in China where you don't tend to get the same availability of foreign books. E.g.

- **UK**: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0321440307/ (works)
- **US**: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321440307/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321440307) (works)
- **JP**: http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/0321440307/ (works)
- **CN**: http://www.amazon.cn/dp/0321440307/ (doesn't work)

You probably need to add the marketplace in somehow to the redirection link.

Comment: excellent, thanks for the info from someone in the know!

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, interesting.

This problem appears to be specific to *products* and not *books*. Consider:

- http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1408810603
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1408810603](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1408810603)

and

- http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0735619670
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735619670](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670)

but for a product, even an international one...

- http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002Y27P46
- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B002Y27P46](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Y27P46)

or

- [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B002Y27P3M](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Y27P3M)
- http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002Y27P3M

... not so much.

Comment: In case you missed it, there's a nice answer by Gareth. The identifiers used are mostly site specific.

Comment: yes, I commented on his answer.. so I hoped that was.. obvious...