# How do I bypass the automatic affiliate linking on Amazon links?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, advertising

Is there a way to bypass the automatic Stack Exchange affiliate linking when I post an Amazon link?

Comment: Seriously? How do you expect [se] to earn?

Comment: @Sathya There are other ways for them to earn, like through Careers, their other ads, or through sales of their hidden product [Stack Exchange Enterprise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available/16055#16055).

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to use the site/platform for their content to profit yourself (in whatever way) yet you are unwilling for them to use your content in order to make money so that they can continue to provide you with the platform?  Welcome to the future of the internet people.

Comment: @Mokubai No, I don't want to profit *anyone*. Not Stack Exchange, not even me.

Comment: Let me get this straight: **the sole purpose of this post is to notify the SE team that there are ways in which users can not let them earn money.** It's up to them whether or not they want to work around these methods.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi your last paragraph in your now edited answer clearly goes what you mention

Comment: @Sathya Can't you see that I was being sarcastic?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi with your posts and behaviour, no.

Comment: ***Never be sarcastic online*** if you don't know how to.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Why don't you try making a maintaining a website this large (and others, eg. superuser.com, askubuntu.com) without getting any money. Anyway, what is the problem in clicking these sponsored links? *You're* not losing anything.

Comment: Amazon Affiliate links are one of the most unobtrusive and user-friendly ways to raise revenue for a site. Users would be linking to/visiting Amazon anyways, who cares if Stack Exchange makes a small referral fee? It doesn't affect the price the user pays at all, and it helps the site out without requiring obtrusive display advertising.

Comment: @nhinkle There are certain bugs with the affiliate linking that affect links to products only sold in countries other than the U.S.

Comment: Would be nice. +1

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways to bypass that:

One way is to change the URL from `http://` to `https://` as in the following example:

Without it (see how the link is tracked when you mouse over it): [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00EOE0WKQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EOE0WKQ)

With it (see how the link is no longer tracked): [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00EOE0WKQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EOE0WKQ)

Another way is to remove the `www` part and replace it with `smile` (i.e. replace `amazon.com` with `smile.amazon.com`) as in the following example: http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00EOE0WKQ/

Comment: So your alright with giving to charity but not Stackexchange?

Comment: @Ramhound Well, technically, nonprofits are searching for ways to get money because they actually *need* it, but for-profits are already earning enough money and just *want* more money. But that's not the point of this post (not anymore, it isn't).

Comment: `https` links now also get converted.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - I would say its safe to say those charities bring in more money then SE.  You would be fine with the affiliate links if you were allowed to use your own.  Your argumenet is flawed and it hasn't been the first time.

Comment: @Oded How about AmazonSmile links?